# Entity Framework: Foreign Key in code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-framework-6, code-first

What is wrong in my code that i get below error:

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values

Code:

Class Food:

```
public class Food
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public short Id { get; set; }

    //some Property
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

Class Person:

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //some Property
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BestFoodId")]
    public Food BestFood { get; set; }
    public short BestFoodId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Food> FavoriteFoods { get; set; }
}
```

Seed Method:

```
 protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
    {
        Food food1 = new Food() { Name = "foo1" };
        Food food2 = new Food() { Name = "foo2" };
        Food food3 = new Food() { Name = "foo3" };

        context.Persons.AddOrUpdate(new Person()
        {
            FirstName = "Jack",
            BestFood = food2,
            FavoriteFoods = new List<Food>() { food1, food2, food3 }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Cause of the error: confused associations

This happens because Entity Framework, by convention, assumes that the *inverse property* of `Person.BestFoodId` is `Food.Persons`. Stated differently: `Person.BestFood` and `Food.Persons` are assumed to be the two ends of a one-to-many association, having `Person.BestFoodId` as foreign key.

You can verify that by adding an `[InverseProperty]` attribute to `BestFood`:

```
public class Person
{
    ...
    [ForeignKey("BestFoodId")]
    [InverseProperty("Persons")]
    public Food BestFood { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

This causes the same error.

This error --no valid ordering-- always indicates a chicken-and-egg problem. In your case, EF tries to insert the foods, which need the generated Id of the inserted person as foreign key, while the inserted person needs the generated Id of the inserted `foo2` food.

#### Solution: explicitly mapped association

In reality, `Person` and `Food` have two associations:

- 1-n: `Food` can be `BestFood` of n people.
- n-m: n `Food`s can be the `FavoriteFoods` of m people.

In your model, `BestFood` doesn't have an inverse property, which *could* have been something as ...

```
public virtual ICollection<Person> BestFoodOf { get; set; }
```

... but it isn't necessary and because it's missing, it obscures how EF infers the associations.

You can fix this by explicitly mapping the associations, for instance in the `OnModelCreating` override of your `DbContext` subclass:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.BestFood)
            .WithMany() // No inverse property
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.BestFoodId)
            //.WillCascadeOnDelete(false)
            ;

modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasMany(p => p.FavoriteFoods)
            .WithMany(f => f.Persons)
            .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("PersonId")
                       .MapRightKey("FoodId")
                       .ToTable("PersonFavoriteFood"));
```

I have commented out `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)`. You either have to add this line, or add ...

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

... to prevent multiple cascaded delete paths (a SQL Server restrictions).

Having this in place, EF knows how to determine a valid ordering for the inserts: it will will first insert the foods, then insert the person (using the generated `foo2` Id as foreign key) and then the junction records in the `PersonFavoriteFood` table.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a circular dependency.

**Answers** are here:

- [Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153208/unable-to-determine-a-valid-ordering-for-dependent-operations)
- [Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760311/unable-to-determine-a-valid-ordering-for-dependent-operations)
- [Entity Framework Code First Circular Dependices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371214/entity-framework-code-first-circular-dependices)
- [Entity Framework 4: inheritance and Associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675960/entity-framework-4-inheritance-and-associations)
- [Entity Framework Circular Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811975/entity-framework-circular-reference)
- [Code First Circular Reference Foreign Key Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053776/code-first-circular-reference-foreign-key-configuration)
- [How to configure a self referencing object in entity framework](http://roland.kierkels.net/c-asp-net/how-to-configure-a-self-referencing-entity-in-code-first/)

---

**Optional improvements:**

- You should declare your [navigation property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738520) as [virtual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/9fkccyh4.aspx)!
- If you are using C# 6.0 or above, change your [`[ForeignKeyAttribute]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute) Data Annotation definition to `[ForeignKey([nameof(BestFoodId))]` to avoid errors with hard coded property names. [`nameof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn986596.aspx) is a really cool compiler feature! :)

Comment: Thanks for your attention ;)

Comment: You are welcome my friend! But I hope that I was able to help you at least a little bit ;)

Comment: You are great. I serach and read several tutorial before ask question but each scenario is good for self and i cann't solve my problem. My question's code is very simple. Evrey body test it and your answer easeily.